# Custom cell with .Xib xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm following this tutorial (http://www.alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/) to create my own custom cell with .xib in Xamarin IOS.

The problem is that the get cell is never called.

I set the sources to my table like this :

```
            InfoTableView.Source = new InfoTableSource(friendChallenges);
```

InfoTableView is a table view set in my storyboard ( not in code behind ).

Somebody already implement a custom cell like this and have the same problem ?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Did you miss link when you said "this tutorial"? Would be nice to get definition of "friendChallenges" and UI code to recreate the problem

Comment: Yes, i forgot it, sorry ^^'

Comment: What about definition of "friendChallenges" and UI code to recreate the problem